# Simple Linear Algebra Proof - Determinants

Tags: proof-writing

Prove or disprove the following statement:

If R is the RREF of A, then det A = det R.

So far, I think that this is true, considering A and R are row equivalent, and that the determinant changes as we row reduce in order to compensate for the changing rows. Although, I'm not sure how to go about proving this statement.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Remember that scaling a row also scales the determinant.

Comment: Hint: look at rref($2I$).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix
$$
A =\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The determinant is  $\det A = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8$ by multiplying down the diagonal. If you row reduce $A$ to a new matrix $R$ then what is the determinant of $R$?